# EF Core 3.1.3: Generating an extra column when using .Include() with basic Parent/Child relationship tables

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1, ef-power-tools

I'm having some trouble diagnosing an error (**Invalid column name 'AgencyOfficeId'**) I'm receiving when I attempt to use Entity Framework Core 3.1.3 using the **.Include()** extension method.  I'm trying to return a collection of parent records (AgencyEmployee) and corresponding relationship records.  Below is the C# code I'm attempting to run to return a List and that includes their associated AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship records.  (C# Models and DbContext configurations are below.)

```
return _context.AgencyEmployee
   .Include(xref => xref.AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships)
   .ToList();
```

The raw SQL that EF Core generates when running the code above is the following:

```
SELECT [a].[Id], 
   [a].[AgencyOfficeId],    <----- EF Core is adding this column for some reason
   [a].[DisplayName], 
   [a].[FirstName], 
   [a].[LastName], 
   [a].[MiddleName], 
   [a].[PreferredName], 
   [a].[Suffix], 
   [a].[Title],
   [a0].[Id], 
   [a0].[AgencyEmployeeId],
   [a0].[AgencyOfficeId],
   [a0].[IsPrimaryInRole], 
   [a0].[JobTitle]
FROM [entity].[AgencyEmployees] AS [a]
   LEFT JOIN [entity].[AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships] AS [a0] ON [a].[Id] = [a0]. 
[AgencyEmployeeId]
ORDER BY [a].[Id], [a0].[Id]
```

I have three models that represent tables in MS SQL Server: **AgencyOffice**, **AgencyEmployee**, and **AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship**.  I'm using EFPowerTools' Reverse Engineer feature to generate the following C# models:

**AgencyEmployee**:

```
[Table("AgencyEmployees", Schema = "entity")]
public partial class AgencyEmployee
{
    public AgencyEmployee()
    {
        AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships = new HashSet<AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship>();
    }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string PreferredName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship.AgencyEmployee))]
    public virtual ICollection<AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship> AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships { get; set; }
}
```

**AgencyOffice**:

```
[Table("AgencyOffices", Schema = "entity")]
public partial class AgencyOffice
{
    public AgencyOffice()
    {
        AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships = new HashSet<AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship>();
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string FormalName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    [Column("FEIN")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Fein { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string OfficeCode { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string DomicileState { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsSatelliteOffice { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship.AgencyOffice))]
    public virtual ICollection<AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship> AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships { get; set; }
}
```

**AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship**:

```
[Table("AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships", Schema = "entity")]
public partial class AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship
{
    public Guid AgencyOfficeId { get; set; }
    public Guid AgencyEmployeeId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryInRole { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AgencyEmployeeId))]
    [InverseProperty("AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships")]
    public virtual AgencyEmployee AgencyEmployee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AgencyOfficeId))]
    [InverseProperty("AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships")]
    public virtual AgencyOffice AgencyOffice { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the DbContext configuration for each table/model inside of the **OnModelCreating()** method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AgencyEmployee>(entity =>
{
   entity.ToTable("AgencyEmployees", "entity");

   entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

   entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasMaxLength(500);

   entity.Property(e => e.FirstName).HasMaxLength(200);

   entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasMaxLength(200);

   entity.Property(e => e.MiddleName).HasMaxLength(200);

   entity.Property(e => e.PreferredName).HasMaxLength(100);

   entity.Property(e => e.Suffix).HasMaxLength(50);

   entity.Property(e => e.Title).HasMaxLength(50);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<AgencyOffice>(entity =>
{
   entity.ToTable("AgencyOffices", "entity");

   entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

   entity.Property(e => e.AppointmentDate).HasColumnType("date");

   entity.Property(e => e.DomicileState).HasMaxLength(100);

   entity.Property(e => e.Fein)
      .HasColumnName("FEIN")
      .HasMaxLength(100);

   entity.Property(e => e.FormalName)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasMaxLength(250);

   entity.Property(e => e.OfficeCode).HasMaxLength(100);

   entity.Property(e => e.ReportName)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasMaxLength(250);

   entity.Property(e => e.ShortName)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasMaxLength(250);

   entity.Property(e => e.TerminationDate).HasColumnType("date");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationship>(entity =>
{
   entity.ToTable("AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships", "entity");

   entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.AgencyOfficeId, e.AgencyEmployeeId })
      .HasName("UQ_entity_AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships")
      .IsUnique();

   entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

   entity.Property(e => e.JobTitle).HasMaxLength(100);

   entity.HasOne(d => d.AgencyEmployee)
      .WithMany(p => p.AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships)
      .HasForeignKey(d => d.AgencyEmployeeId)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
      .HasConstraintName("FK_AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships_AgencyEmployeeId");

   entity.HasOne(d => d.AgencyOffice)
      .WithMany(p => p.AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships)
      .HasForeignKey(d => d.AgencyOfficeId)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
      .HasConstraintName("FK_AgencyOfficeAgencyEmployeeRelationships_AgencyOfficeId");
});
```

Here is a relationship diagram of how the MS SQL Server tables are setup:
[image: SQL Server relationship diagram]

Does anyone have any ideas on where I may have gone wrong?  If I attempt to select **AgencyOffices** and related relationship records EF Core generates valid SQL without any extra fields.  The problem only occurs when I attempt to select **AgencyEmployees**.

If anyone needs any additional info just let me know.  Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: This is the query when MySQL is used: https://pastebin.com/b4eNRnuK. So the source code is somehow okay, no additional invalid `AgencyOfficeId` column generated in the SQL query. Unfortunately, I don't have an SQL Server test this query/code.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm really at a loss.  I have probably over a dozen of similar junction/cross-reference tables that are set up the same way and those are working just fine.  Thanks for taking a look!